# How to convert to proper datatypes in dynamic expression builder on .net core?

Tags: entity-framework, .net-core, lambda

I have the below code which handles filters by dynamic expressions. This works fine if the datatype is string, however, if it is number or date, i don't know how to handle that.. can someone please help

```
MemberExpression member = Expression.Property(param, filter.Name);
var propertyType = ((PropertyInfo)member.Member).PropertyType;
var converter = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(propertyType);

filter.Value.Aggregate(
   (Expression)Expression.Constant(false),
   (acc, next) =>
       Expression.MakeBinary(
       ExpressionType.Or,
       acc, Expression.Equal(member, Expression.Constant(next))));
```

Payload

```
{
  "pageFilters": [
    {
      "name": "firstName",
      "condition": "Equals",
      "value": [
        "john", "sam"
      ]
    }
  ]
}

{
  "pageFilters": [
    {
      "name": "age",
      "condition": "Equals",
      "value": [
        "30", "40" --> tried "value":[30,40] as well
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```